# MATLAB Matrix Inversion: inv(X) versus X\eye(size(X))

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-inverse

Based on the [wonderful MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html), it is clear that when solving systems of linear equations, it is preferable to use `X\b` to `inv(X)*b` for reasons of numerical stability. It also notes that `X^(-1)` is equivalent to `inv(X)`. But it makes no mention of the relationship between `X\eye(size(X))` and `inv(X)`! I would like to use the more succinct notation, and it makes sense that `inv(X)` should be the preferred form, but cannot find confirmation of this anywhere in the documentation.

The docs mention that `\` uses Gaussian elimination whereas `inv` uses LU decomposition.

When I tested them using an example similar to [that provided in the documenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html#bu6sfy8-1), I find that the two are not equivalent:

```
n = 500;
Q = orth(randn(n,n));
d = logspace(0,-10,n);
A = Q*diag(d)*Q';

y = inv(A);
z = A\eye(n);
disp(['Difference: ', num2str(norm(inv(A) - A\eye(n)))]);
```

The results:

```
Difference: 2.2957e-05
```

Can anyone explain which of the two methods is more numerically stable?

Comment: Use `timeit` to make meaningful comparisons between runtimes. Single `tic` and `toc` calls are essentially useless for benchmarking purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that! Just removed that, since I'm more interested in numerical stability anyways.

Comment: I guess that you have already ran this a lot of times to find the numerical stability and timing differences? Please update the question with those data.

Comment: My problem here is that I can get the differences, but that information is useless since I don't know which one is "more correct". I would need to use a matrix where the inverse is known beforehand to benchmark, but then I fear my results would only be applicable to how those algorithms perform on that specific type of matrix...

Comment: `\ `  uses a huge amount of algorithms, not Gaussian elimination. However, the real question you need to ask is: do you really need the matrix inverse? Or are you using this inverse somewhere else? Because in the second case, you want to use `\ `, in that "somwhere else" place, and that would be by far the most accurate and stable method

Comment: Does it really matter in practice, or is this a question of academic nature? My advice to you is - whenever you have a choice between code that "does the job better" versus code that "looks better", you should keep the more performant code active and possibly keep the other option as a comment nearby. Maybe both of them are "good enough"? How did you reach the conclusion that `\\` uses Gaussian elimination? [It depends on the input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt4jslc-6)!

Comment: @Dev-iL I found it on another MathWorks documentation page: "A better way, from the standpoint of both execution time and numerical accuracy, is to use the matrix backslash operator x = A\b. This produces the solution using Gaussian elimination, without explicitly forming the inverse."

Comment: You can alternative go to the main documentation page of `\ ` and look at the algorithms: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt4jslc-6

Comment: There are various ways to go about this, it's a question of what you want to achieve at the end of the day. See for example: [`decomposition`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/decomposition.html).